# Node js and Redis Undefined JSON property

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, redis

I'm getting undefined when I try to obtain a JSON property from a redis function.

When I use this console outputs what is suppose to:

```
redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
 console.log("new message add in queue "+ data + " channel");
 socket.emit(channel, data);
});
```

Console:

> > new message add in queue {"message":"A new message!","user":"John Doe"} channel

When I try and get a property from data I get undefined:

```
redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {

  console.log("new message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel");
  socket.emit(channel, data);
});
```

> new message add in queue undefined channel

I've also tried to get the data property like this with no luck

```
data.message
```

It's strange because in my client side script I can use data.message and it works just fine.

Comment: can u just once try JSON.parse(data).message just might be data is in stringify format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data object that you get is a string, not an object. To get the message you should do `JSON.parse(data).message`

By looking the source code of `redisClient` you can notice that `publish` method and `on('message')` event are using string arguments. When using `JSON.parse` it is recommended to wrap it in `try/catch` block. The string may be not valid, and an error will be thrown.

```
redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
  try{
     data=JSON.parse(data)
  }
  catch(e){
     return console.log('data is not an JSON string',data)
  }
  console.log("new message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel");
  socket.emit(channel, data);
})
```

**More info**:

- https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/ff9b727609ea125919828f7373e40082fd432eec/examples/psubscribe.js